# how to select the text field without keyboard in iOS swift

Tags: swift3, keyboard, uitextfield

can anyone tell me how to select the text field without keyboard coming up  in iOS swift.i only need the selected textfield not the keyboard

Comment: Do you need the textfield to be editable?

Comment: You can dismiss the keyboard `self.view.endEditing(true)`

Comment: @DávidPásztor no need but it should be selected but keyboard shouldn't come

Comment: Then if you set editable to false, I think `textField.becomeFirstResponder()` shouldn't bring up the keyboard, but cannot test it at the moment.